# Toggle button in Magento 2 in frontend Form

Tags: magento2.3, forms

In frontent customer edit form, I need to show toggle button as below
[image]

In admin it is showing using component JS. Not able to use HTML and component in frontend.

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Add Html like this**

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

> **And Add CSS**

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 35px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #588242;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)